Can Layer3 Switches share the same static ip pool?
In a building, 2 of Layer3(A, B) Switches is active.
A has been used ip address pool (x.x.x.0/26, G/W:x.x.x.1). => Under Layer 3 of A, ip address (x.x.x.3~5) used.
Can B use the same ip pool (x.x.x.0/26, G/W:x.x.x.30) without ip address conflict? => Under Layer 3 of B, ip address (x.x.x.10~12) will be used.
I can't make the same situation for test.

You are referring to DHCP? Do you require any redundancy? Without, a split is unnecessary. You should add a network diagram and the intended switch configurations to your question for us to make better sense of it.
